# Use of java image in pythonic OpenCV

Tags: java, python, scala, opencv

I'm fetching some images via HTTP:

```
val ostream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
ImageIO.write(imageurl, imageType, ostream)
val istream = new ByteArrayInputStream(ostream.toByteArray)
```

(it is actually scala, but this code itself using Java libs, so there is no scala specific magic).
Then I'm pushing `istream` to database (in my case it is GridFS, which is a part of MongoDB).
And now I need to use it image (bytearray) in OpenCV (w/ python bindings):

```
db = Connection(myserver,myport).DB
fs = GridFS(db)
bytearray = fs.get(id).read()
```

Given that, how can I create `Mat` for use in OpenCV functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need [imdecode](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imdecode) function.

Comment: It does exists in native C++ OpenCV, but I can't find `imdecode` in python binding [reference](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html), neither in code.

Comment: @om-nom-nom What version of OpenCV are you using? This function is available since OpenCV 2.2. Without this function you can only save image to temporary file and read it with LoadImage or decode image with another library.

Comment: 2.1.0-2 (python-opencv) from gijzelaar repo. I've seen newer packages of opencv, but no new python bindings in that repo (I know that I can make opencv by my own, using code from willowgarage or some other site, but I would prefer not to do that if there is another way). Writing images to disk and then swapping them back will work but this will dramatically decrease performance.